# image is saved as portrait, but appears as landscape in webapp

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, web-applications

I am building a web app, and (sometimes!) when i save an image at the serverside, (portrait) and i try to access directly everything is ok.(figure1)
from my web app though it appears as landscape and i have not done anything to the code. it seems just random(figure 3). Also when i try to view the image info, it shows again as landscape(figure 2).

[image: figure 1]

[image: figure 2]

[image: figure 3]

EDIT:
code to show the image: `<img width='100%' height='auto' src='"+element.path+"'>`

where element.path the absolute path of the image, received by jquery ajax.

I should also mention, that this problem happens only when i take photos with an iphone 5s and upload them to the server.

Comment: How are we suppose to know if you don't show us your code ?

Comment: as i said, i dont think its a coding problem,(im just showing the image like: `<img width='100%'   height='auto' src='"+element.path+"'>` inside a div  (where element.path is the absolute path of the image on the server(as shown on the addressbar in the figure 1) )

Comment: If the photo is taken by phone, the issue is probably related to the orientation of the photo. When you take a photo, the phone save in the exif data the orientation of the phone. Windows not use this data and and displays it wrong.
We use this plugin for resize image and reorientation: http://imageresizing.net/

Comment: @GermanoPlebani thanks that actually might take me somewhere i didnt know that

Comment: I remember now this beautiful plugin https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Load-Image provides a complete solution to the EXIF orientation problem